# How do you adjust the width of a custom composite's element? (Drupal 9 webform)

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

A webform I am customizing has 9 elements in a composite. Since there are too many of them, the composite is exceeding the fieldset you will see below.

[This is the picture of the composite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxz6T.png)

I would like to shrink the size of the composite and adjust the widths of some of the elements (like **Amount** since it shouldn't take that many space, and maybe make **Type** element wider).

[I followed along this solution but the size would not change even](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2940788) when I added

```
wrapper_attributes:
  width: 20%
```

Does anyone have experience with adjusting the widths of composite's elements ?

[P.S. To be visual-friendly, here is where I added the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URNgV.png)

Comment: Maybe you want to put a `style` attribute (ie CSS)... Something like `["wrapper_attributes"] = ["style" => "width: 20%"]`

Comment: It does work when I format it in attachment PDF, but in the actual website, I don't know how should I change it other than adding what I tried in YAML file.

Comment: It seems you are in the back end of drupal and therefore using the default admin theme (correct me if I am wrong). So another way would be to create your own admin theme (easily done by ingeriting one of the default admin themes) and adding your own css. Or actually, you could try just using another theme as your admin theme.

Comment: I attached a picture of where I added the code. Would you please take a look for me?

Comment: In 14 years of using drupal I have never seen the interface that the image shows. It must be a contrib module I have never used I suppose.

Comment: It is what the webform module provides. I mainly work with them on the website.

Answer (score -1):

Other Idea: Change in CSS padding, margin or border-line.

Comment: It seems he is on the back end and using the default admin theme. He would need to add a custom admin theme to be able to easily change the css. This is an incomplete answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).